# What happens after Jetty calls ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jetty

This has been bugging me for a long time so I thought i'd throw it out there. Maybe a Jetty expert will see it.

I have a J2EE app that works just fine. When I start the jetty server host I see all of the correct info come through the log console, including the "Context Initialized" message in the code below.

However, if i deploy a new version of the app by copying a root.war file to the webapps folder, I see the "Context Initialized" log, but the startup stops there and no further startup.  The server doesn't respond, so i have to restart it after every deploy.

My question is, where do a look next to track down what is hanging up.  What happens after ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()

```
public class ApplicationListener implements ServletContextListener {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationListener.class.getName());


@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent)   {
    log.info("Context Initialised"); //this is the last thing to come out of the log before it hangs if jetty is restarting due to a new .war file detection


}
```

when i start jetty from scratch - i see the above the the rest of these logs are spat out which indicates a normal start:

```
2015-12-05 12:40:33.214:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor /opt/nimbits/contexts at interval 1
2015-12-05 12:40:33.215:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: /opt/nimbits/contexts/javadoc.xml
2015-12-05 12:40:33.222:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: /opt/nimbits/contexts/test.xml
2015-12-05 12:40:33.233:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/opt/nimbits/webapps/test.war!/ to /private/var/folders/x4/vh_dqlln1hn_vkk8jgz9tcf00000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_-any-/webapp
2015-12-05 12:40:33.528:INFO:oejs.TransparentProxy:TransparentProxy @ /javadoc-proxy to http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs
2015-12-05 12:40:33.557:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Java EE 6 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html) states the following regarding Servlet lifecycle:

> 1. If an instance of the servlet does not exist, the web container
>
>    1. Loads the servlet class.
>    2. Creates an instance of the servlet class.
>    3. Initializes the servlet instance by calling the init method.
> 2. Invokes the service method, passing request and response objects. (i.e. GET or POST requests)

The EE 6 Tutorial states that ServletListener "reacts" to Servlet `init()` and `destroy()` calls.  Which implies that your listeners are being called after `init()` completes at step 1.3.  You could try overriding your servlet's init method and adding print statements to check for yourself.

Given the above, it looks like your app is getting hung up on step #2, which is the invocation of the service methods themselves (GET/POST).  I would recommend adding additional logging to servlet init and doGet/doPost method just to be sure.  If that still doesn't fix your issue, [try enabling Jetty trace](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Logging) so you get more detailed logging on what could be going wrong.